# Make a Discord bot DM a specific person

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a piece of code to annoy my friend but I cannot seem to find a way to DM him specifically. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import random
from random import choice
@commands.command()
    async def annoy(self,ctx):
        friend_id=#id number 123243 etc
        responses=["a","b","C"]
        await ctx.send("He has been notified.")
        await friend_id.send(random.choice(responses))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found!

```
friend_id=self.client.get_user(#Friend's ID)
await friend_id.send("Message")
```

Replace `self.client` with whatever your bot is called, as not everyone's will be named `client`.
Also removed `self.` if not inside of a cog, obviously.